# j.sip.TransactionAlreadyExistsException

Tags: sip, voip, jain-sip, sipp

I am running a load test using SiPp server for around 1k calls, Out of that 10 to 15 calls are failing due to TransactionAlreadyExistsException. I have verified that sip CallId is also unique for each call. How to handle this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are about the Via branch id, not the call id. Make sure the Via branch id is unique. Make sure you are not using some kind of timestamp as a branch id for example because when you do it too fast the timestamp between attempts may come the same.

Comment: Hi Vladimir..  I have verified that branch id from top most via is also getting generated uniquely from random number. Not sure why still this exception is thrown in SipProvider class in Jain SIP

Comment: Then most likely cause is retransmissions. As you go under higher load, retransmissions come in and they have a null transactions. Perhaps your app is trying to create a new transaction on the retransmission (which is identical to the original and thus has same branch id).

Comment: Yes agree. Does that mean this error is not causing any failures. Right?